# Blit function not working, is loop going to fast?

Tags: python, pygame

Hey I'm working on a gravity function for my Super Mario bross. I would like a smooth movement of gravity.But my player is like teleporting from top to the ground.

I though it was the loop that was going too fast and pygame couldn't blit the image but i've tried to slow the loop with time.sleep() or pygame.time.wait()
It is not working.
At the start it's like this : 
[Image : Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqVka.png)
[Image : One sec later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcCfj.png)
Thanks for helping !

```py
def moove(self,keys):     
        if(self.gravity()):
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.orientation = "Left"
                if not(self.x - vel<0) and not self.collision_with_walls():
                    map.draw()
                    self.rect.x -= vel
                    camera.update(player)
                    self.draw_player()
```

```py
def gravity(self):
        refresh = 0
        self.collision_with_ground = False
        while not self.collision_with_ground:
            self.rect.y += 1
            blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,sol_sprites,False)
            if not(blocks_hit_list == []):
                self.collision_with_ground = True
                self.rect.y -= 1
                map.draw()
                player.draw_player()
                return True 
            else:
                map.draw()
                player.draw_player()
                pygame.time.wait(10)
```

Comment: I assume that you need something which rapidly and repeatedly calls a method like `gravity()`, but that method itself should only move the player a small amount each time. It looks like `gravity()` is attempting to move the player several times with each call.

Comment: my method ```gravity()``` is mooving down my player of one pixel until the player touches the ground, on every frame loop

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true. See the answer from @Hoog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line: `while not self.collision_with_ground:` you are ensuring that you will not leave this loop until your player has reached the ground.  You will never blit (which is outside this loop) until this loop has been left.  Try `if` instead of while and move your other functions outside that loop (you should probably take them out of this function):

```
def gravity(self):
        refresh = 0
        self.collision_with_ground = False
        if not self.collision_with_ground:
            self.rect.y += 1
            blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,sol_sprites,False)
            if not(blocks_hit_list == []):
                self.collision_with_ground = True
                self.rect.y -= 1
                map.draw()
                player.draw_player()
                return True 

        map.draw()
        player.draw_player()
        pygame.time.wait(10)
```

Comment: so you cant blit while you are in a while loop ? i though the function would have been blit while the while exucution, gonna try this! Edit : Thanks its working !!!

Comment: You can blit within a while loop, you just don't want a while loop here.  Your `gravity()` function should be called once per frame, and should print at most once per frame (REALLY it shouldn't print the map or player here as those should be in their own functions called from the main game loop after `gravity()`)